# Tomcat and domain and SSL

Tags: tomcat

I have tomcat 8.x running on port 8080 (for http) and 8082 (https) on Windows Server 2008 r2.

I need to add a legitimate signed certificate instead of a self signed one. I acquired a certificate for the domain (example.com). The domain is pointed to the Windows server.

Now, I've added the keystore and installed the cert on the windows server.
But when i access https://example.com:8082/ on the web, my cert says self signed.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: fyi, i ve already configured tomcat to use the particular keystore in server.xml

Comment: Can you share your `server.xml` config?